Edge-coloring on bipartite graphs with different conditions on left and right nodes
I am considering the following edge-coloring problem on bipartite graphs with different conditions on left and right nodes.

Given: A bipartite graph $G = (V_L \cup V_R, E)$
Aim to: Find a 2-coloring (say, RED and BLUE) on the edges in $E$, i.e., $f: E \mapsto \{0,1\}$
To Optimize: For each left node $v_L \in V_L$, we aim to make the edges incident to $v_L$ as monochromatic as possible, I am considering the following two specific variants of the objective

[Entropy] Minimize $\sum_{v_L \in V_L} \operatorname{Entropy}(f(v_L, v_R): v_R \in N(v_L))$, where $N(v_L) \subseteq V_R$ is the neighborhood of $v_L$
[Number of violations] Minimize $\sum_{v_L \in V_L} \sum_{v_1, v_2 \in N(v_L)} |f(v_L, v_1) - f(v_L, v_2)|$


Subject to: For each right node $v_R \in V_R$, one and only one BLUE edge should be incident to $v_R$, i.e.,
$$\sum_{v_L \in N(v_R)} f(v_L, v_R) = 1, \forall v_R \in V_R.$$


I am wondering the difficulty of this problem and what kind of algorithms we can use to solve it.

Background
The above problem was derived from the following scenario I thought about.
Say we have an item set $V_L$ and we have a group of people $V_R$, where each person $v_R \in V_R$ is associated with a candidate item set $N(v_R) \subseteq V_L$.
Now, we want to pick an item for each person, while assuming that

(1) The "popularity" of each item is universal across different people, which corresponds to the monochromatic condition for $V_L$
(2) We exactly pick a single item for each person, which corresponds to the "one and only one BLUE edge" condition for $V_R$

